# Is there a unique way to construct the overall spatial wavefunction for identical particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, bosons, identical-particles

While studying the quantum mechanics of $N$ identical particles, I stumbled upon formulas for generalizing the spatial wavefunction for bosons:

$$\psi(x_1,...,x_N)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N!\prod_\alpha N_\alpha!}}\sum_p \psi_1(x_1)...\psi_N(x_N)$$

and for fermions, using the [Slater Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant):
$$
\psi(x_1,...,x_N)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}}
\begin{vmatrix}
\psi_1(x_1) & \psi_1(x_2) & ... & \psi_1(x_N)\\
\psi_2(x_1) & \psi_2(x_2) & ... & \psi_2(x_N)\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\psi_N(x_1) & \psi_N(x_2) & ... & \psi_N(x_N)\\
\end{vmatrix} 
$$

My question is this: **Are these the only ways of constructing wavefunctions for bosons and fermions?** If no, how else do we do it? If yes, does the uniqueness of the formulas above point toward some deep fundamental fact about particles?

The way I understand it, the only requirement here is that the spatial wavefunction for the system of bosons be symmetric, and for the system of fermions, anti-symmetric. That said, I have not come across other schemes for constructing these wavefunctions, and I am curious if there are such schemes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Determinants and permanents are not the only way.

There is a general result for the permutation group that, if you want to construct a fully symmetric wavefunction by combining the spatial and spin parts, then both parts must have the same permutation symmetry (*i.e.* must transform by identical irreps).  This applies also for multidimensional representation of the permutation group.

If you want to construct a fully antisymmetric wavefunction, you must combine a spatial and spin part of conjugate symmetries.

As an example, it is possible to construct a fully symmetric 4-particle state by combining spatial states and spin states in the 3-dimensional irrep $\{3,1\}$, and a fully antisymmetric state by combining a spatial part in $\{2,1,1\}$ and a spin part in $\{3,1\}$ (both of which of course are $3$-dimensional).

The explicit sums of products of the various parts are given by the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for the permutation group (in my example, those would be CG’s for $S_4$).

This method does have the advantage of providing you with state of specific total spin but algebraic cost increases with $n$, and tables of CG’s for $S_n$ aren’t so common (much less pre-packaged codes).

On balance, determinants or permanents are more common, and chemists in particular have developed various clever methods to extract angular momentum or spin information when needed.

Answer (score -1):

The fact is that all states of an N-particle system **can** be written in this way. This is because the Hilbert space of such a system is a subspace of the $n$-fold tensor product of the one-particle Hilbert space. However, there are certainly other methods of describing states in this Hilbert space. A particularly useful one is in terms of occupation number. Since the particles are indistinguishable, the state is completely determined by saying how many particles are in a given state. In the case of bosons this number is unrestricted. In the case of fermions this number is restricted to be $0$ or $1$ due to antisymmetry.

To be specific, consider a one particle Hilbert space $\mathfrak{H}$ spanned by states $\{|\phi_1,\phi_2,\cdots\rangle\}$. The correspondic bosonic/fermionic $N$ particle space is spanned by kets of the form $|n_1,n_2,\cdots\rangle$ with $n_1+n_2+\cdots=N$. It corresponds to $n_1$ particles being in the state $|\phi_1\rangle$, $n_2$ particles being in the state $|\phi_2\rangle$, etc... In the bosonic case $n_1,n_2,\dots \in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. In the fermionic case $n_1,n_2,\dots \in\{0,1\}$.